# Postgresql granting a username to specific database

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to create a user that only has access to one database. It's telling me database doesn't exist but clearly it does by following.

```
postgres=# \l
                                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 GarsDB    | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |            | libc            |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |            | libc            |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |         |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=# grant all privileges on database GarsDB to gars;
ERROR:  database "garsdb" does not exist
postgres=# grant all privileges on database garsdb to gars;
ERROR:  database "garsdb" does not exist
postgres=#
```

Any ideas what could be going on?  I've only been using Postgres recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a case-sensitive database name because you used the dreaded double quotes when you created it. This means you now have [to use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) the double quotes always:

```
grant all privileges on database "GarsDB" to gars;
```

I highly recommend to **not** use case sensitive identifiers. I would rename the database to be all lowercase:

```
alter database "GarsDB" rename to garsdb;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked and I switched it all lowercase.   I've been using SQL Server for 15 years and it's not case sensitive so have to get in grove of Postres.

Comment: @RandyR: Postgres isn't case sensitive either if you don't use the double quotes. But enclosing an identifier in double quotes makes it case-sensitive as required by the SQL standard.  `alter database "GarsDB" rename to GARSDB;` would actually achieve the same thing because `garsdb`, `GarsDB` and `GARSDB` are all the same name - but different from `"GarsDB"`

Comment: Thanks again.  I know I created this database through pgAdmin gui.   Maybe it put quotes around it for me?